# ToggleButton onCheckChangeListener

Tags: java, android, eclipse, togglebutton

I'm making an app that has a record button and a togglebutton. The record button starts recording sound and the togglebutton declares whether the record button has to be HELD to record or only pressed once. This is how I'm trying to achieve it:

```
touchToRecord.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener(){

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                boolean isChecked) {
            saveCheckedState("touchToRecord", isChecked);

            if (isChecked)
            {
                recBtn.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){

                    @Override
                    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                        {
                            recBtn.setImageResource(com.whizzappseasyvoicenotepad.R.drawable.record_btn_pressed);
                            chTimer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
                            chTimer.setText("00:00:00");
                            chTimer.start();
                            chTimer.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
                            startRecording();
                        }
                        else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
                        {
                            recBtn.setImageResource(com.whizzappseasyvoicenotepad.R.drawable.record_btn);
                            chTimer.stop();
                            chTimer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
                            chTimer.setText("00:00:00");
                            chTimer.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
                            stopRecording();
                            nameAlert();
                        }
                        return true;
                    }
                });
            }
            else if (isChecked == false)
            {

            }
```

As you can see, if togglebutton is 'on' or 'checked', the record button has to be held down to record, and when you let og of the button, it stops recording. Now this works but it only have one flaw. I am saving the isChecked state to sharedpreferences, so if I turn the togglebutton 'on' and then restart the app, the togglebutton will remain 'on', but I'll have to turn it back off and on again for it to work. So if I restart the app, it'll be still 'on' but it won't work.

Also, I haven't yet written the code for what happens if the togglebutton is false, as you can see.

**My code now:**

```
if (touchToRecord.isChecked() == true)
    {
         recBtn.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                {
                    recBtn.setImageResource(com.whizzappseasyvoicenotepad.R.drawable.record_btn_pressed);
                    startTimer();
                    startRecording();
                }
                else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
                {
                    recBtn.setImageResource(com.whizzappseasyvoicenotepad.R.drawable.record_btn);
                    stopTimer();
                    stopRecording();
                    nameAlert();
                }
            return true;
            }
        });
    }

    if (touchToRecord.isChecked() == false)
    {
        recBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                if (recorder == null)
                {
                    recBtn.setImageResource(com.whizzappseasyvoicenotepad.R.drawable.record_btn_pressed);
                    startTimer();
                    startRecording();
                }
                else if (recorder != null)
                {
                    recBtn.setImageResource(com.whizzappseasyvoicenotepad.R.drawable.record_btn);
                    stopTimer();
                    stopRecording();
                    nameAlert();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

OnCheckedChangeListener:

```
touchToRecord.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener(){

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                boolean isChecked) {
            saveCheckedState("touchToRecord", isChecked);
        }
    });
```

Get togglebutton state from shared preferences:

```
touchToRecord.setChecked(getCheckedState("touchToRecord"));
```

Comment: Why you are saving the state 'checked' in shared preferences?

Comment: @Namenlos because I want the app to remember the setting, so that the user won't have to change it everytime the app is opened. Is there something wrong with that?

Comment: No it's okay, I got you wrong ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is about your logic. You have `onCheckedChangeListener`, which means you will check if it is **On** or **Off** when user change the `Toggle Button`. So when you kill app and start again, since there is no change on `Toggle Button`, it won't work.

Put your `onTouchListener` outside the `onCheckedChangeListener`. In your `onCheckedChangeListener` set your status(**On** or **Off**) and inside the `onTouchListener` check if it is **On** or **Off** and perform your actions.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is exactly the kind of answer that I needed, I knew there was something wrong with my logic but I couldn't point my finger to it. Just one more thing though, should I do all of that inside onCreate?

Comment: Maybe you forget to take coffee break :) I also always put there, so it should be okay. Don't forget to mark answer accepted for future references

Comment: Just one more thing :p can I make an if statement inside onCreate? For example: if togglebutton is checked, then implement ontouchlistener, else if togglebutton is unchecked, then implement onclicklistener. Since now I just implemente dboth onclicklistener and ontouchlistener and then I wrote if statement inside those, and it doesn't quite work as I intended

Comment: What do you need onClickListener for?

Comment: Well, as I said in my original post, if togglebutton is checked, I want the record button to record only of it is touched and held (onTouchListener is for that) and if the togglebutton is not checked, you have press the button to start recording and then press again to stop recording (onClickListener is for that) if you know what I mean

Comment: Got it, I haven't pay attention. You are right, create an if statement, if Toggle is On create onTouchListener, if it is Off create onClickListener.

Comment: Please check my original post again, I posted the code that I have now. It still won't work properly for some reason, it doesn't matter whether the togglebutton is toggled or not now, it will implement the onTouchListener. Any idea what could be wrong now?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35476/discussion-between-gokhan-arik-and-matthew)